# Task tracker not running,the job is scheduled but doesnt run. how to fix?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have been running some benchmarks and i am new to hadoop and hdfs. I have got the setup and things running and they were working fine. But now i am faced with this issue, jps on the master shows
1. secondary name node
2. job tracker
but not the name node and task tracker.

similarly jps on the slave nodes shows only name node, but task tracker is not running.

I usually run the job as the user and not root, but mistakenly i ran it as root and then when i exited and ran the job as user, i found the job doesn't start. then with jps i found the task tracker is not running.

I am new to hdfs, and not sure how to debug and solve this, it would be great if you can give some pointers/help on this one, i did try google and couldnt find relevant answers.

Edit: I tried clearing tmp files, killing obsolete java process and restarting. still i get the same issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Kill all java process, after stopping the cluster
2. remove /tmp hadoop pids
3. verify file permission errors, but looking at hadoop/logs/*.log file in name node and data node, this gave me useful info in debugging the issue.

this link was helpful,
http://felixtechnique.blogspot.com/2010/09/no-namenode-to-stop-no-tasktracker-to.html